# About change URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How to change "_" to "-" in url using htaccess in Url:
ex : Change  http://mysite.net/us_es_lk to http://mysite.net/us-es-lk.
Thanks

Comment: Have you got an attempt that fails?

Comment: I try to use str_replace to change my Url but it not work, i have research and some guid use htaccess but i'm not good in this, so can u help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file add:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "_" to "-"
RewriteRule ^us_es_lk$ /us-es-lk? [L,R=301]
```

Result:

`http://mysite.net/us_es_lk` becomes `http://mysite.net/us-es-lk`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I tried it and the url was change but it wrong when redirect link. http://mysite.net/us_es_lk is OK but http://mysite.net/us-es-lk error 404. May help ?

Comment: 404 means page not found; You need a webpage located at that path, however, your original question was answered.

Comment: Thanks very much. I haved do it. Thanks for your helping :)

Comment: You're quite welcome — please click the check mark next to the answer. Cheers! :)